# VBA Macro to convert only certain footnotes to endnotes in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, footnotes

first post, hope I do this right.

I have a Word doc with lots of footnotes that are all custom marks, none automatically numbered. There are two types of custom mark: numerals and letters. So either 1, 2, 3 or a, b, c.
I want to convert ONLY the footnotes with letter marks, into endnotes.

I can convert all footnotes to endnotes with:

```
Sub ConvertFootnotesEndnotesTEST()
' Convert
ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Convert
With ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Content.Start, End:= _
ActiveDocument.Content.End).FootnoteOptions
.Location = wdBottomOfPage
.NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
End With
' Renumbering
With ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Content.Start, End:= _
ActiveDocument.Content.End).EndnoteOptions
.Location = wdEndOfDocument
.NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
.StartingNumber = 1
.NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleLowercaseArabic
End With
End Sub
```

I thought stipulating the NumberStyle in the above would work; it doesn't. I'm not really a programmer, just a keen Word user.
I also tried

```
If Selection.Footnotes.NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
Then Selection.Footnotes.Convert
```

but that doesn't work either.

I would be VERY grateful for some help with this! Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, you cannot convert an individual footnote directly. You also can't query the number style in the way that you want to; that number style would indicate Word's sequential lettered notes, not custom marks. So, the best approach is probably to cycle through each footnote in the document, decide if it's one you want to convert, and then convert it as a member of a footnote collection (which always only includes one note). This is how I would do it:

```
Sub ConvSomeFootnotes()
'Declare some variables.
Dim objFNote As Footnote
Dim objDoc As Document

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument

    'Loop through each footnote in the document's footnotes collection.
    For Each objFNote In objDoc.Footnotes
        'This only works because you are using custom marks, which can be read as regular text. If you were using standard sequential markers you'd need a different approach.
        'Check that the text of the footnote reference matches the character class that contains all lowercase letters.
        If objFNote.Reference.Text Like "[a-z]" Then
            'If it does, we convert all of the footnotes within the range (which in this case happens to be just the one footnote we are looking at).
            objFNote.Reference.Footnotes.Convert
        End If
    Next objFNote
End Sub
```

As noted in the comments, this only works because you are using custom markers. If you weren't, you'd need another approach to tell whether the footnotes were lettered or numbered (a more complicated approach). I tested this on Word 2010; I can't say for certain if it would work as-is on a Mac or in a much earlier version of Word.